# unable to upload image from android to python flask server, show the error org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException in android

Tags: java, android, python, flask

I'm using Multipartentity for uploading image to python server. I got an error is Response from server: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.0.104:5000 refused. Can explain anyone, why this come error?

This is the backend task code:

```
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    long totalSize = 0;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
        progressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(UPLOAD_URL);

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });
            String imagefilepath = null;
            String filemanagerstring = filePath.getPath();;
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(filePath);
            if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                imagefilepath = selectedImagePath;
            } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                imagefilepath = filemanagerstring;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
            }

            File sourceFile = new File(imagefilepath);

            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("aadharimage", new FileBody(sourceFile));
            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        // showing the server response in an alert dialog


        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

This is the url

public String UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.0.104:5000/static/android";

This is the phyton code

```
@app.route('/static/android', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'file' not in request.files:
         flash('No file part')
         return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['aadharimage']
    if file.filename == '':
         flash('No selected file')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file :
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

but you have written the additional code is,

```
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
   return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                           filename)
```

why did you write this code.
is this code is necessary to upload images?

Comment: why the flask-sql alchemy tag?? you should put the java tag

Comment: can you please post the error you are getting on the flask side??

Answer (score 0):

I've forgotten a lot from java and android, but the error may come from your flask function on the last line

```
return redirect(url_for('upload_file', filename=filename))
```

**you are redirecting to the same URL and it doesn't have a filename argument**

After checking in [flask doc about](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/) uploading file, you need to add another method for download the uploaded file and redirect to that one

check this from the doc:

> Now one last thing is missing: the serving of the uploaded files. In
>   the upload_file() we redirect the user to url_for('uploaded_file',
>   filename=filename), that is, /uploads/filename. So we write the
>   uploaded_file() function to return the file of that name. As of Flask
>   0.5 we can use a function that does that for us:

And change the last line of your upload_file method to this :

```
return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
```

And create the uploaded file method :

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)
```

**SOLUTION 2 :**

Or If you just need to save the image in the flask server you could return a success message to the user saying that the image was saved.

change your python code to this  :

```
@app.route('/static/android', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
     print request
     print request.values
    # check if the post request has the file part
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        # flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    print(request.files['aadharimage'])
    file = request.files['aadharimage']
    # if user does not select file, browser also
    # submit a empty part without filename
    if file.filename == '':
        print(file)
        # flash('No selected file')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        print(file)
        print(file.filename)
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        # print filename
        print(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return "an image has been saved "
```

This is only for the python part

**Also Make sure that your flask app is running on 192.168.0.104 and port 5000**

Comment: you mentioned here, @app.route('/uploads/<filename>) as it is can i copy the code or some changes.

Comment: did you runned your flask application?? edit your question by adding the code used to run the flask app

Comment: i unable to find the problem from python-flask or android app.

Comment: i think may be problem is from android app side.could you see both codes and help me sir.